# How to create PFObject <SubClassing> with NSDictionary

Tags: nsdictionary, parse-platform, subclassing

I Have a PFobject subclassing registered in AppDelegate but when I try to set a NSDictionary, it crash with message:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'PFObject values must be serializable to JSON'
```

Does anyone know how to do it right, using PFObject with ???

Here's my class:

Ranking.h

```
@interface Ranking : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *final;
@end
```

Ranking.m

```
@implementation Ranking

@dynamic final;

+(NSString *)parseClassName{
    return @"FinalRanking";
}
@end
```

And here's the method:

```
-(void)saveNewRanking{
    Ranking *newRanking = [[Ranking alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *dic = @{@1:@20,
                      @2:@18};
    newRanking.final = dic;
    [newRanking saveInBackground];
}
```